# Keypresses acting sporadically

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a full-screen overlay running on top of a windowed border-less game when I activate my overlay key-presses seem to work only sometimes. Often they are delayed or even never activated. The mouse seems to work well, it is just the keys that act sporadically. Any ideas why this is happening?

EDIT:
I think my question is a bit misleading. When I said the key presses seem sporadic I meant that they are sporadic in the game I am playing and not on my overlay form. I don't even need the ability to catch key events on my form I just need it to draw over the game window without interfering with it. When I activate my form and switch back to the game the controls begin to lag behind and act strangely. Like I said though the mouse seem to work perfectly fine.

Comment: Have you tried anything to resolve this, or any code to show us how you're subscribing to the events?

Comment: it's probebly cus' the key-presses event is catched on the controls in the overlay, you need to catch them there - for example if you create a textBox, you will catch the key-presses event of the textbox int the textBox and not in the overlay

Comment: This could be a host of things, you need to provide more information, like exactly how you are trapping the keystrokes.  My guess is whether you think so or not, your input is tied to the same thread as your game ui output.  When the Game UI gets intensive, your keypress can get delayed.

Comment: Basically what I do is set the form to maximized border-less and topmost with transparency. Then I set the opacity to 30%. I then hook into keyboard presses with the method described in this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx When the 'M' key is presses I call either Hide() or Show() depending on the forms current state. When I show the form I ALT+TAB back to the game   . My form then stays on the top and I can continue to play the game with the overlay but like I said the problem is that with the overlay is shown keystrokes are delayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... I accidentally set KeyPreview to true on the overlay and it was causing the game to receive delayed key inputs.